# How do I list unsynced files on a removable media?

Tags: linux, sync, removable-media

1. How do I list all unsynced/unwritten files on a usb-stick/sd-card or other removable-media?
2. Can I be certain all files are synced after I run `sync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How do I list all unsynced/unwritten files on a usb-stick/sd-card or other removable-media?

Use `lsof` to *list open files* then use `grep` to filter the results to your mountpoint.

> 2. Can I be certain all files are synced after I run sync?

If `sync` returns successfully then *at that moment* all files are synced.  An unmount (or "eject" in the GUI) calls `sync` in the background before actually unmounting.